# Javascript - buffer video from blobs source?

Tags: javascript, video, cross-browser, buffer, blob

### Context:

Fiddling with javascript.

Html5 browser.

### Question:

Is it possible to have, say, two video blobs and buffer their content in a video tag and play them smoothly without concatenating them at first ?

The underlying is : is it possible to dynamically add data to the video buffer in javascript in the browsers **at any moment** (the video may have already started to play and we still add data from a blob after that)?

All the solutions seems to need the whole data at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the Media Source API which is, unfortunately, only available on Chrome. AFAIK it only works with webm container and vorbis and vp8 codecs.

```
var ms = new MediaSource();

var video = document.querySelector('video');
video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(ms);

ms.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(e) {
    ...
    var sourceBuffer = ms.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"');
    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(oneVideoWebMChunk);
    ....
}, false);
```

[Here is a little demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html)

[W3C draft](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/)

Comment: I feared that answer :) i will have to find a way to smooth transition between two videos then..